# Running a piece of code only once after app is upgraded

Tags: ios, objective-c

I want to run a piece of code -- for data cleanup -- only once after the user upgrades the app or installs the app from scratch.

Putting the piece of code in `didFinishLaunchingWithOptions` method wasn't helpful since -- it seems -- after the app is opened after the upgrade (without hard-killing it before the upgrade) the `didFinishLaunchingWithOptions` event wasn't triggered.

I can put the piece of code in the `applicationWillEnterForeground` event handler and have it conditioned on a `dataCleanupDone` flag being `FALSE`. Is there a neater solution?

Comment: you can use the !UserDefaults.standard.bool forKey and you pass the app version, if it's true, the code inside it will run only when the app version changes, or you install the app from scratch, and then set it to true

Comment: After further checks, `didFinishLaunchingWithOptions` event handler is run automatically when app is upgraded. During the upgrade the iOS kills the running app then installs the upgrade and launches the new app. So we can put the cleanup code in the `didFinishLaunchingWithOptions` event handler (we would still need a flag to record that the cleanup had been done).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After the clean up set a flag (`kCleanUpCompletedKey`) in the user preferences. Check if this flag is set when the app becomes active.

Example:

```
- (void)applicationDidBecomeActive:(UIApplication *)application {

     if ([self shouldDoCleanUp]){
        // do your clean up

        // after successful clean up:
        NSUserDefaults *prefs = [NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults];
        [prefs setBool:YES forKey:kCleanUpCompletedKey];
     }
}

- (BOOL)shouldDoCleanUp {
    NSUserDefaults *prefs = [NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults];

    if ([prefs objectForKey:kCleanUpCompletedKey]){
      return YES;
    }
    return NO;
}
```

Comment: Thank you. The `applicationDidBecomeActive` event handler is the place I was looking for to put the cleanup code in.

Answer (score 0):

You need to add appversion in your new App version in preference and then 
call method onUpgradingApp if prefrence value is 0 then set it to 1 and run this code

```
integerValue CurrentAppVersion = 2; // suppose
```

Inside Appdelegate :

```
 NSUserDefaults *defaults = [NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults];

        NSInteger oldVersion = [[defaults objectForKey:@"appVersion"] integerValue];

        if (oldVersion == 0) // if old app is running
        {
            oldVersion = 1;
        }

        if (oldVersion < CurrentAppVersion)
        {
            [self onUpgradingApp:oldVersion newVersion: CurrentAppVersion];
            [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] setObject:[NSNumber numberWithInteger:CurrentAppVersion] forKey:@"appVersion"]; //save new version in preference
        }



    -(void)onUpgradingApp:(NSInteger)oldVersion newVersion:(NSInteger)newVersion
    {
        NSString *query;
        switch (oldVersion)
        {
            case 1:
             {
              // clean data here
             }
             break;
            default:
                break;
        }



    }
```

Answer (score 0):

**SWIFT VERSION**

you can use same logic.

1- Define your app version in the info.plist file

example: Bundle versions string, short: 0.1.1

[image]

And then you should increase that variable every time you have a new version.

2- in your controller create a variable app_version and get the right version from that info.plist file.

example: let version = dict["CFBundleShortVersionString"] as? String

3- Use the !UserDefaults.standards.bool to check if the app version changes, if true run your code and then set it to true

example:

```
if (!UserDefaults.standard.bool(forKey: appVersion)) {

        /* Your code */

        UserDefaults.standard.set(true, forKey: appVersion)
        UserDefaults.standard.synchronize();
    }
```

Hope this helps.